# PyQt QTableView resizeRowsToContents not completely resize on initialisation

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview, pyqt6

I have a minimum example here of a QTableView widget that displays a long string that I want word wrapped when I start the app.

```py
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QMainWindow,
    QTableView,
    QHeaderView,
    QApplication,
)
from PyQt6.QtCore import (
    Qt, 
    QEvent,
    QAbstractTableModel,
    QSize,
    QEvent
)
import sys

text = """A long string which needs word wrapping to fully display. A long string which needs word wrapping to fully display. A long string which needs word wrapping to fully display."""

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.table = QTableView()
        header = self.table.horizontalHeader()
        header.setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeMode.Stretch)
        
        self.table.horizontalHeader().sectionResized.connect(self.table.resizeRowsToContents)
        
        self.model = TableModel([[text] for i in range(50)])
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        
        self.table.resizeRowsToContents()

    def changeEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Type.WindowStateChange: 
            self.table.resizeRowsToContents()

        return super(MainWindow, self).changeEvent(event)

class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data[0])

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.lastWindowClosed.connect(app.quit)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec()
```

When I run the above I get this

[image]

but when I resize the window manually just slightly, I get what I'm expecting

[image]

How would I get the second image as the state when the app is started? I thought calling `self.table.resizeRowsToContents()` in the `__init__` method would do it. Another question is, why does `self.table.horizontalHeader().sectionResized.connect(self.table.resizeRowsToContents)` work upon resizing when `resizeRowsToContents()` does not work in the `__init__` method?

Comment: Try to delay the resizing: `QTimer.singleShot(0, self.table.resizeRowsToContents)`. The cause is because when you call it in the `__init__` the window has not been shown yet, it's internal layout hasn't been activated and the table just "assumes" a default size. Delaying that call allows the event queue to process all that before finally adjusting the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why does self.table.horizontalHeader().sectionResized.connect(self.table.resizeRowsToContents) work upon resizing when resizeRowsToContents() does not work in the **init** method?

Because the window isn't rendered yet, that's why the QTableView doesn't know yet how big the text is in order to resize the rows.

> How would I get the second image as the state when the app is started? I thought calling self.table.resizeRowsToContents() in the **init** method would do it.

You could separate the population of the table from the **init** method, or delay it, until Your widget is rendered, preferably inside the class itself, but you can do something like this:

```
# ...
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.lastWindowClosed.connect(app.quit)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
w.table.resizeRowsToContents() # I just added this line
app.exec()
```